# Apache LDAP authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, active-directory, ldap, gateway

i have configured apache with Active directory to perform authentication for a web page, everything works perfectly, when the user enter the username and password, Apache validate it against AD and it works.
The thing which is not working is that when the user enter the domain e.g. domain\username instead of only username, Apache won't be able to authenticate it, it says not allowed.

i would like to strip the domain using RewriteCondition or something similar, i mean if the user enter the domain\username, Apache should keep only username and remove the "domain\" any help / hint from you?
thanks in advance.

ProxyPass "/sso" "http://webserver1/sso" timeout=30
ProxyPassReverse "http://webserver1/sso" "/sso"

`<Location "/sso">`
    LDAPReferrals off
    AuthType                   Basic
    AuthName                   "Web Application"
    require valid-user
    RequestHeader unset username
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1]
    RequestHeader add username %{RU}e
                AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=queryuser,CN=Users,DC=activdir01,DC=us,DC=com"
                AuthLDAPURL "ldap://127.0.0.1:389  /CN=Users,DC=activdir01,DC=us,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "Password"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
`</Location>`

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of the LDAP authentication part of your httpd.conf?

Comment: @T-Heron i just added the section above. from my point of view it fail when the user enter domain\\username at the level of AuthLDAPURL "ldap://127.0.0.1:389/CN=Users,DC=activdir01,DC=us,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"